# String "1" gets added in php mail()

Tags: php, email

I'm sending an email using php's mail() function. My code is as following:

```
$to      = email@email.com;
$subject = "Subject of email";


ob_start();
echo include('emailcontent.php');
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$headers = 
'From: Email <email@email.com>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: Email <no-reply@email.com>' . "\r\n" .
"Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

For some reason the string "1" is added at the end of the message. This happens in the include('emailcontent.php'), because if I add another string to the message after the include the "1" is added before that addition.

In the emailcontent.php is no 1 or whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo include('emailcontent.php');
```

Remove the `echo`. That echo puts `1` in there

You might ask why does echo put 1 in there when its not added anywhere? Because when your file is successfully included the return value of that include is TRUE and when you send that to `echo` it prints `1`. Try

```
echo 2==2;   //1
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you are echoing the php page? You have to include the page like,

`include('emailcontent.php');`

Remove the `echo` it is causing the 1.